# Serverless to AWS - Gitlab CICD

Tags: gitlab-ci, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm developing an application using [Serveless Framework](https://serverless.com/) and I want to deploy it in AWS using GitLab CICD.

Following the best practises documentation I've setup a single repo with the following structure:

```
│
├── services
│   ├── customer-api
│   │    └── handler.js, serverless.yml
│   └── payment-api
│        └── handler.js, serverless.yml
│
├── serverless-common.yml
└── .gitlab-ci.yml
```

So inside of the services folder I've several folders (one for each api / lambda).
I've also setup the following simple GitLab CI/CD

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - deploy

dev:
  environment: dev
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - npm config set prefix /usr/local
    - npm install -g serverless
  script:
    - serverless deploy --stage dev --verbose
```

The problem that I've is that I want to deploy only the lambdas that have changes.

Should I go directory by directory inside the services folder and run the `serverless deploy` for each api?:

```
  script:
    - cd customer-api
    - serverless deploy --stage dev --verbose
    - cd ..
    - cd payment-api
    - serverless deploy --stage dev --verbose
```

How are you managing serverless deployments using GitLab CI/CD?

Comment: As of now this functionality is not there with GitLab CI/CD , GitLab will create Cloud-formation stack in aws(behind the scenes) and use that stack for all further operation on that stack like update , delete etc. Stack will go through all the function and resources you have mention in template irrespective of any changes happened or not and compare  the changes with old artifacts by itself. So if you run your pipeline with minimal changes in template then you will observe that the time taken of deployment will be less in comparison of any new resources creation or modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and regarding your folder structure , if you can do something like this :

```
│
├── services
│   ├── customer-api
│   │    └── handler.js, customer-api.yml
│   └── payment-api
│        └── handler.js, payment-api.yml
│
├── serverless.yml
└── .gitlab-ci.yml
```

and give references for those function in main serverless.yml file like this:

```
functions:
  customer-api: ${file(./services/customer-api/customer-api.yml)
  payment-api: ${file(./services/payment-api/payment-api.yml)
```

then you don't need to go inside each folder to execute serverless.yml file:

```
script:
     - serverless deploy --stage dev --verbose
```

will be info.
for more info you can check [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/)